# How to Make Python AWS S3 Boto3 Code Robust to Intermittent WiFi

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, raspberry-pi, wifi, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to create a program on a Raspberry Pi that will intermittently take pictures and send them to AWS S3.

About half the time, everything works fine. Problem is that the WiFi receiver on the Raspberry Pi that I have is pretty awful, and it loses connection constantly. I know it isn't my WiFi because all other devices on the network are fine. After the connection is lost, it searches until it finds it again, usually 15-30 seconds or so. Then the cycle repeats after a minute or two.

I am trying to create code that will attempt to connect to S3, and on failure, will continue trying until the connection is restored. So far, however, connection errors still cause a hard stop.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

allbuckets = 0

while allbuckets == 0:
    try:
        allbuckets = s3.buckets.all()
    except:
        allbuckets = 0

for bucket in allbuckets:
    print(bucket.name)
```

If the connection is solid, this works fine:

```
>>> %Run boto_test.py
derek-raspberrypi-pictures
stpaul-academy-middleschool-showcase-2020-part2
```

If the connection has been temporarily lost, however:

```
>>> %Run boto_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 263, in send
    chunked=self._chunked(request.headers),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 343, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 841, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 301, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0xb52a6950>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/boto_test.py", line 15, in <module>
    for bucket in allbuckets:
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/collection.py", line 83, in __iter__
    for page in self.pages():
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/collection.py", line 161, in pages
    pages = [getattr(client, self._py_operation_name)(**params)]
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 622, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 641, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 137, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 256, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 269, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 283, in send
    raise EndpointConnectionError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/"
```

Any suggestions on how to make this robust to the intermittent WiFi connection would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try boto3 client. It will make request immediately when you call it. `s3 = boto3.client('s3')`, then `allbuckets = s3.list_buckets()`

Comment: I tried that. It changed the format of allbuckets a bit, but I could have worked around that. However, the error if WiFi isn't connected still shows up. Same as before. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the power management from the wifi interface on the RPi which should keep it active.

```
$ sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Comment: Needed a reboot to take effect, but seems to work great now. Thanks!